# How to register plugins that implement multiple interfaces via SimpleInjector

Tags: simple-injector

In assembly A0 I have

```cs
public interface IC {
...
}

public interface IA : IC {
FuncA();
}

public interface IB : IC {
FuncB();
}
```

In assembly A1 I have

```cs
public class C1 : IA, IB {
...
}
```

In assembly A2 I have

```cs
public class C2 : IA, IB {
...
}
```

In assembly A3 I have

```cs
public class C3 : IA {
...
}
```

I want to register all implementations of interface `IA` and `IB` in all assemblies. This can be done via the plugins example at [Registering plugins dynamically](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=plugin#plugins).

```cs
var pluginAssemblies = from file in new DirectoryInfo(pluginDirectory).GetFiles()
where file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll"
select Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName);

var pluginTypesIA = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IA), pluginAssemblies);
var pluginTypesIB = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IB), pluginAssemblies);

container.RegisterCollection<IA>(pluginTypesIA);
container.RegisterCollection<IB>(pluginTypesIB);
```

How can I ensure that dependencies on `IEnumeralbe<IA>` and `IEnumerable<IB>` will return the same instance for `C1` and `C2` in both these collections? How can I ensure that `C1` and `C2` are registered as `Lifestyle.Singleton`?

I also tried to work with the example for [Register multiple interfaces with the same implementation](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation) and [Batch / Automatic registration](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#batch-automatic-registration) but I get exceptions on `container.Verify()` because it complains that interface `IA` is already registered and I need to call `container.RegisterCollection` instead.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Which which lifestyle should those instances be registered?

Comment: @Steven Lifestyle.Scoped or Lifestyle.Singleton. I have a set of plugins similar to what I described in the question which need to be Scoped and another set of plugins which need to be Singleton, the two sets implement different interfaces so I can easily figure out which. I forgot to mention IA and IB both derive from a common interface IC. Will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register them all as scoped using the following code:

```cs
var pluginAssemblies = 
    from file in new DirectoryInfo(pluginDirectory).GetFiles()
    where file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll"
    select Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName);

var registrations = (
    from assembly in pluginAssemblies
    from type in assembly.GetTypes()
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where typeof(IA).IsAssignableFrom(type) || typeof(IB).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(type, container))
    .ToArray();

container.Collection.Register<IA>(registrations.Where(Implements<IA>));
container.Collection.Register<IB>(registrations.Where(Implements<IB>));

private static bool Implements<T>(Registration r) =>
    typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(r.ImplementationType);
```